# How to check phone is silent or not for play sound or vibration

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am working on calling App.So when the call is received I want to play a native sound. It's working but my problem is when the phone is silent, phone only vibrates.And when silent is off play sound.I am using below code to achieve this. But it's not working.Please tell me what I do?

```
 // play sound when call is coming
        func playSound()
        {
            guard let url = URL(string: "/Library/Ringtones/Opening.m4r") else
            {
                print("url not found")
                return
            }
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player?.numberOfLoops = -1
            player?.prepareToPlay()
            player?.play()
    }
```

Comment: So, your problem is that you want it to always play the sound even if the device is silent, is it?

Comment: No, play a sound when the phone is not silent.otherwise vibration.

Comment: Try changing the `category` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` instead of `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`

Comment: But vibration is not working. How to vibrate when phone is silent ?

Comment: The code you posted does not contains anything to make the phone vibrate. 
Besides, I believe there is no way to check if the device is silenced.

Comment: To vibrate your phone you need to import AudioToolBox and write following code AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)) or AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

Comment: @PaulMarshal it vibrates only one time.How to vibrate continuously?

Comment: You need to use AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))